# Swagger UI-SpringBoot hide the model name

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using the swagger with Spring Boot.Swagger version is 2.9.2
How can i hide the Model Name in the Swagger UI, just want to show the model properties on Swagger UI. As mentioned in the screenshot EndCustomerDto is my Model name that needs to be hidden, just want to show it's properties only. [image]

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use photoes of ur code, use screenshots (`Win+Shift+S` for Windows f.e.). That's a rule, not a contract. Now to the answer.
You need to use properties from [here](https://springdoc.org/v2/#properties) to set up needed
configuration. I hope you use `SwaggerConfig.java` class or anything similar to it. It consists of something like this:

```
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi apiGroup(){
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("Api")
                .pathsToMatch("/api/**")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI apiInfo() {
        final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
        return new OpenAPI()
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
                .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes(schemeObj_if_any)
                .info(new Info()
                        .title("Ur API title")
                        .description("Ur description")
                        .version("1.0"));
    }
}
```

In that class u can use any of props described [here](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/). The prop u need is `defaultModelsExpandDepth` for *ALL* models or `defaultModelExpandDepth` for *ONE* model. Hope it helps.

Comment: `defaultModel(s)ExpandDepth` options are not related to what OP wants.

Comment: @Helen that depends on the purpose of hiding models names. Idk any of security rules that would require such an action. But if there is any - a css solution would be clearly wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style to your Swagger UI CSS. This hides the schema names inside operations, but keeps them in the Models/Schemas section at the bottom of Swagger UI.

```css
.swagger-ui .model-example .model-title {
  display: none;
}
```

For example, you can add this style inside the `<style>` section in Swagger UI's `index.html` page:

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<html>
  <head>
    ...

    <style>
    .swagger-ui .model-example .model-title {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  ...

</html>
```

Since you're using Springfox, you need to use either [this](https://springdoc.org/#customizing-swagger-static-resources) or [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1108#issuecomment-167120179) approach to apply Swagger UI CSS customizations.